# PythonMagic: How do a composite with a dissolve value?

Tags: imagemagick, composite, pythonmagick

I like to do this with PythonMagick:

```
composite -dissolve 40 over.png base.png new.png
```

I have tried:

```
import PythonMagick
base = PythonMagick.Image("base.png")
over = PythonMagick.Image("over.png")
base.composite(over,0,0,PythonMagick.CompositeOperator.DissolveCompositeOp)
base.write("some.png")
```

That works fine, but how can I specify the dissolve value?

Thanks in advance

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662184/python-pil-lighten-transparent-image-and-paste-to-another-one), I would recommend staying with PIL since PythonMagick seems to be [inac](http://sxoop.wordpress.com/2006/11/29/whither-pythonmagick/)[tive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445985/where-can-i-find-pythonmagick-documentation). I also looked into [Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/)'s  documentation, but it fails to mention how to specify extra options for `composite`. I would stay away from these libraries, and instead use the direct CLI provided by ImageMagick.

Comment: I agree and thanks to your solution regarding PIL I am happy staying to use it.