# change opacity/alpha/transparency in png image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a png image with transparency on it and I would like to change its opacity keeping the transparency of the pixel just add a percentage or something.
I tried using `putalpha` but it just destroys the transparency in the image.

What I want is something like the `opacity` property in css.

Thank you.

```css
img{opacity:.2}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/2zGGyYB.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

found a way to do it.

```
image=Image.open("star_blue.png")
opacity=0.5
bands=list(self.image.split())
if len(bands)==4:
    bands[3]=bands[3].point(lambda x:x*opacity)
    new_image=Image.merge(image.mode,bands)
```

found the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662184/python-pil-lighten-transparent-image-and-paste-to-another-one)

thanks mmgp

Answer (score 0):

png image is transparent where all channels are zero. The 4'th channel is the opacity. so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread("http://i.imgur.com/2zGGyYB.png")
plt.imshow(im)
im[:,:,3]=np.where(im[:,:,2]>0,0.2,0)
plt.imshow(im)
```